# How do I preserve style background color for pandas DataFrames when saving jupyter notebooks as a PDF?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm finding that I lose background style colors in my printed DataFrames when I save a jupyter notebook to a PDF. It also happens if I view as pure HTML -- where the colors show up -- and then print that HTML to PDF. All colors simply vanish.

How do I get the background colors to still show when saving content to PDF?